# How to set data into a complex json dictionary in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Basically I need to set data into a JSON API Payload before I need to send it in the API request.
I have 2 files,

1. text file which has JSON payload format, say json.txt
2. yml file which has actual data, say tdata.yml
   Im writing a python code to create actual payload by inserting data from yml file to JSON payload format

Content of file 1

```
{
    "mpls_routing":
    {   
        "add_novel":
        {
            "device_ip": "DEVICE_IP",
            "discoveryHelloHoldTime": "DISCOVERYHELLOHOLDTIME",
            "discoveryHelloInterval": "DISCOVERYHELLOINTERVAL",
            "discoveryTargetedHelloHoldTime": "DISCOVERYTARGETEDHELLOHOLDTIME",
            "discoveryTargetedHelloInterval": "DISCOVERYTARGETEDHELLOINTERVAL",
            "downstreamMaxLabel": "DOWNSTREAMMAXLABEL",
            "downstreamMinLabel": "DOWNSTREAMMINLABEL",
            "initialBackoff": "INITIALBACKOFF",
            "instanceId": "554972419",
            "interfaceName": "INTERFACENAME",
            "isEntropyLabelEnabled": "ISENTROPYLABELENABLED",
            "isExplicitNullEnabled": "ISEXPLICITNULLENABLED",
            "isLoopDetectionEnabled": "ISLOOPDETECTIONENABLED",
            "isNsrEnabled": "ISNSRENABLED",
            "keepAliveInterval": "KEEPALIVEINTERVAL",
            "ldpId": "LDPID",
            "ldpIpMask": {
                "address": ""
        },
            "ldpPepSettings": [
                {
                    "com.novel.xmp.model.managed.standardTechnologies.ldp.LdpPepSettings": {
                        "labelDistributionMethod": "DISTMETHOD",
                        "ldpId": "LDPID",
                        "name": "MPLSINTERFACE",
                        "owningEntityId": "OWNINGENTITYID"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "maximumBackoff": "MAXIMUMBACKOFF",
            "sessionHoldTime": "SESSIONHOLDTIME"
        }
}
```

This is the yml data file

```
mpls_interface:
  DEVICE_IP: "10.104.120.141"
  DISCOVERYHELLOHOLDTIME: "15"
  DISCOVERYHELLOINTERVAL: "5"
  DISCOVERYTARGETEDHELLOHOLDTIME: "90"
  DISCOVERYTARGETEDHELLOINTERVAL: "10"
  DOWNSTREAMMAXLABEL: "289999"
  DOWNSTREAMMINLABEL: "24000"
  INITIALBACKOFF: "15"
  INTERFACENAME: "LOOPBACK0"
  ISENTROPYLABELENABLED: "FALSE"
  ISEXPLICITNULLENABLED: "FALSE"
  ISLOOPDETECTIONENABLED: "FALSE"
  ISNSRENABLED: "TRUE"
  KEEPALIVEINTERVAL: "60"
  LDPID: "192.168.0.141"
  MAXIMUMBACKOFF: "120"
  OWNINGENTITYID: ""
  SESSIONHOLDTIME: "180"
  DISTMETHOD: "LDP"
  MPLSINTERFACE: "TenGigE0/0/0/4"
```

I have following code which reads the JSON format file data

```
                template_data = file.read()
                template_data = json.loads(template_data)
                if "add_novel" in template_data:
                    full_template_file = template_data["add_novel"]
                    if testcase_name in full_template_file:
                        template_file_data = full_template_file[testcase_name]
```

And following code which reads the yml file

```
            with open(self.mpls_yml_file) as stream:
                yml_data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
                if "mpls_interface" in yml_data:
                    yml_file_data = yml_data["mpls_interface"]
            return yml_file_data
```

Then I pass both template_file_data and yml_file_data to following code to create the actual API payload.

```
testcase_data = {key: yml_file_data[value] for key, value in template_file_data.items() for k, v in
                             yml_file_data.items()}
            logger.info("\n Testcase data %s" % testcase_data)

            return testcase_data
```

But I'm not able to get the right format since there is nested dictionary and also a array inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The good news is that I don't think you are planning to update the nested elements

I am guessing this because the YAML file does not contain anything for `ldpPepSettings`, for example.

So you could just use the original JSON information for parts where the YAML file does not provide an update. For example:

```
testcase_data = {key: yml_file_data[value] for key, value in template_file_data.items() for k, v in
                             yml_file_data.items()}
```

could become

```
testcase_data = {
    key: 
    (yml_file_data[key] if key in yml_file_data else value) 
    for key, value in template_file_data.items()
}
```

You will still have the problem that the two files have different keys. One has lowerCamelCase and the other has ALLCAPS.

You could try to fudge it like this?

```
testcase_data = {
    key: 
    (yml_file_data[key.upper()] if key.upper() in yml_file_data else value) 
    for key, value in template_file_data.items()
}
```

Comment: I want to replace the CAPS variables in JSON file with the  actual value from the  yml file. And I want to replace the values in nested dictionary and arrays which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to figure it out with your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to do the text search/replace to the JSON file's contents before JSON decode it.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

import yaml

# Load the YAML with values
with open("values.yaml") as stream:
    lookups = yaml.safe_load(stream)

# Load the JSON as text
with open("payload.json") as stream:
    text = stream.read()

# Replace values
for lookup in lookups.values():
    new_text = text
    for old_value, new_value in lookup.items():
        new_text = new_text.replace(old_value, new_value)
    payload = json.loads(new_text)
    print(json.dumps(payload, indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "mpls_routing": {
        "add_novel": {
            "device_ip": "10.104.120.141",
            "discoveryHelloHoldTime": "15",
            "discoveryHelloInterval": "5",
            "discoveryTargetedHelloHoldTime": "90",
            "discoveryTargetedHelloInterval": "10",
            "downstreamMaxLabel": "289999",
            "downstreamMinLabel": "24000",
            "initialBackoff": "15",
            "instanceId": "554972419",
            "interfaceName": "LOOPBACK0",
            "isEntropyLabelEnabled": "FALSE",
            "isExplicitNullEnabled": "FALSE",
            "isLoopDetectionEnabled": "FALSE",
            "isNsrEnabled": "TRUE",
            "keepAliveInterval": "60",
            "ldpId": "192.168.0.141",
            "ldpIpMask": {
                "address": ""
            },
            "ldpPepSettings": [
                {
                    "com.cisco.xmp.model.managed.standardTechnologies.ldp.LdpPepSettings": {
                        "labelDistributionMethod": "",
                        "ldpId": "192.168.0.141",
                        "name": "TenGigE0/0/0/4",
                        "owningEntityId": ""
                    }
                }
            ],
            "maximumBackoff": "120",
            "sessionHoldTime": "180"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function that can navigate as deep as necessary in the JSON (Python dictionary) to substitute the values. Something like this:

```
from yaml import safe_load
from json import load, dumps

YFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/mpls.yaml'
JFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/mpls.json'

def yaml_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as y:
        return safe_load(y)["mpls_interface"]

def json_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as j:
        return load(j)

def merge(d, y):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                merge(v, y)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for e in v:
                    merge(e, y)
            else:
                d[k] = y.get(v, v)
        return d

result = merge(json_data(JFILE), yaml_data(YFILE))

print(dumps(result, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "mpls_routing": {
    "add_novel": {
      "device_ip": "10.104.120.141",
      "discoveryHelloHoldTime": "15",
      "discoveryHelloInterval": "5",
      "discoveryTargetedHelloHoldTime": "90",
      "discoveryTargetedHelloInterval": "10",
      "downstreamMaxLabel": "289999",
      "downstreamMinLabel": "24000",
      "initialBackoff": "15",
      "instanceId": "554972419",
      "interfaceName": "LOOPBACK0",
      "isEntropyLabelEnabled": "FALSE",
      "isExplicitNullEnabled": "FALSE",
      "isLoopDetectionEnabled": "FALSE",
      "isNsrEnabled": "TRUE",
      "keepAliveInterval": "60",
      "ldpId": "192.168.0.141",
      "ldpIpMask": {
        "address": ""
      },
      "ldpPepSettings": [
        {
          "com.novel.xmp.model.managed.standardTechnologies.ldp.LdpPepSettings": {
            "labelDistributionMethod": "LDP",
            "ldpId": "192.168.0.141",
            "name": "TenGigE0/0/0/4",
            "owningEntityId": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "maximumBackoff": "120",
      "sessionHoldTime": "180"
    }
  }
}
```